# Best way to represent deep tree of resources?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there an easy way to reuse a route "segment" along with the controller logic that goes into validating and using parameters in the segment?

For example, I'd like to represent my resources similar to this:

- houses

  - { house address }

    - architecture

      - roof
      - siding
    - rooms

      - living

        - doors
        - windows
      - dining

        - doors
        - windows
      - kitchen

        - doors
        - windows
      - bedrooms

        - [0]

          - doors
          - windows
        - [1]

          - doors
          - windows

Below is one way that could be done. **What's the Better Way?**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
class HousesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<House> Get() => _housesRepo.GetAll();

    [HttpGet("{houseId}")]
    public ActionResult<House> Get(string houseId)
    {
        if (!_housesRepo.TryGetHouse(houseId, out var house))
            return NotFound("Bad house ID");
    }
}

class RoomsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("~houses/{houseId}/rooms/bedrooms/{bedroomId}")]
    public ActionResult<Room> GetBedroom(string houseId, int bedroomId)
    {
        if (!_housesRepo.TryGetHouse(houseId, out var house))
            return NotFound("Bad house ID");
        var bedrooms = house.Bedrooms;
        if (bedroomId < 0 || bedroomId >= bedrooms.Length)
            return NotFound("Bad bedroom ID");
        return bedrooms[bedroomId];
    }

    [HttpGet("~houses/{houseId}/rooms/{roomClass}")]
    public ActionResult<Room> GetRoom(string houseId, string roomClass)
    {
        if (!_housesRepo.TryGetHouse(houseId, out var house))
            return NotFound("Bad house ID");
        var roomsByClass = house.RoomsByClass;
        if (!roomsByClass.TryGetValue(roomClass, out var room))
            return NotFound("Bad room class");
        return room;
    }
}

class ArchitectureController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("~houses/{houseId}/architecture")]
    public ActionResult<string[]> Get(string houseId)
    {
        if (!_housesRepo.TryGetHouse(houseId, out _))
            return NotFound("Bad house ID");
        return new [] { "roof", "siding" };
    }

    [HttpGet("~houses/{houseId}/architecture/roof")]
    public ActionResult<Roof> GetRoof(string houseId)
    {
        if (!_housesRepo.TryGetHouse(houseId, out var house))
            return NotFound("Bad house ID");
        return house.Architecture.Roof;
    }

    [HttpGet("~houses/{houseId}/architecture/siding")]
    public ActionResult<Siding> GetSiding(string houseId)
    {
        if (!_housesRepo.TryGetHouse(houseId, out var house))
            return NotFound("Bad house ID");
        return house.Architecture.Siding;
    }
}
```

But notice how much repetition there is:

- `~houses/{houseId}` route segment
- Validating `houseId` and retrieving the associated `House`

And the repetition only gets worse as the resources get more complex.

It seems that Microsoft pushes people toward having a very flat hierarchy. For example:

- `~houses/{houseId}`
- `~architecture/{architectureId}`
- `~rooms/{roomId}`

But that only hides the problem. For example, a `Room` only makes sense as a component of a `House`, so the `{roomId}` would have to include information about the house's ID as well. Then I would need to parse `roomId` to extract the `houseId` *in addition* to validating and extracting the associated `House` resource.

It would be nice if I could just have this:

```
[Segment("HOUSE")]
[HttpGet("houses/{houseId}")]
public ActionResult<House> GetHouse(string houseId) => _housesRepo
    .TryGetValue(houseId, out var house)
    ? new ActionResult<House>(house)
    : NotFound("Bad house ID");

[HttpGet("[HOUSE]/architecture")]
public string[] GetArchitectureCategories(House house) => new [] { "roof", "siding" };

[HttpGet("[HOUSE]/architecture/roof")]
public Roof GetRoof(House house) => house.Architecture.Roof;

[HttpGet("[HOUSE]/architecture/siding")]
public Siding GetSiding(House house) => house.Architecture.Siding;

[Segment("BEDROOM")]
[HttpGet("[HOUSE]/rooms/bedrooms/{bedroomId}")]
public Room GetBedroom(House house, int bedroomId) => house.Bedrooms[bedroomId];

[Segment("ROOM")]
[HttpGet("[HOUSE]/rooms/{roomClass}")]
public ActionResult<Room> GetRoom(House house, string roomClass) => house
    .RoomsByClass
    .TryGetValue(roomClass, out var room)
    ? new ActionResult<Room>(room)
    : NotFound("Bad room class");
```

That would be very easy to build on. For example, I could quickly add controllers for doors and windows:

```
[HttpGet("[ROOM|BEDROOM]/doors")]
public Door[] GetDoors(Room room) => room.Doors;

[HttpGet("[ROOM|BEDROOM]/windows")]
public Window[] GetWindows(Room room) => room.Windows;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as you indicate, but it's still achievable. First, you want to rely on route prefixes being applied to the controller class itself. In other words, instead of:

```
[HttpGet("~houses/{houseId}/rooms/bedrooms/{bedroomId}")]
public ActionResult<Room> GetBedroom(string houseId, int bedroomId)
```

Use:

```
[Route("houses/{houseId}/rooms")]
public class RoomsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("bedrooms/{bedroomId}")]
    public ActionResult<Room> GetBedroom(int bedroomId)
```

Then, also notice that I took out the `houseId` param there. The logic for this can be moved out into an override of `OnActionExecutionAsync`:

```
private House House { get; set; }

public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    if (context.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("houseId", out var houseId))
    {
        House = await _context.Set<House>().FindAsync(houseId);
        if (House == null)
            context.Result = NotFound();
    }

    await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
}
```

That looks a little complex, but all this is doing is pulling out the `houseId` param from the route and attempting to find an associated house. If none is found, a 404 is returned immediately, otherwise, the `House` property on the controller is set with that house. As a result, each of your actions in this controller can now count on that `House` property being available and can use it accordingly, only having to focus on their own specific behaviors.

Comment: Awesome. Details (such as parameter names and how to convert parameters into objects) can be encapsulated and abstracted away--I like it!

Comment: Based on using `FindAsync`, it shouldn't matter what is passed as `houseId`. For example, if someone tried `/houses/foo/rooms/bedrooms/1`, it should just result in a 404. However, you probably still want to add route constraints to your params: `house/{houseId:int}/rooms` and `bedrooms/{bedroomId:int}`.